# How to prevent name mangling on extern "stdcall" in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi, name-mangling

In `wx.dll`, there is a C language function defined as follows:

```
void __stdcall WXRelease(void *p);
```

I am trying to call it in Rust using stdcall:

```
run --package wxams --bin wxams --target=i686-pc-windows-msvc
```

, but I am encountering some issues:

```
#[link(name="wx", kind = "dylib")]
extern "stdcall" {
    fn WXRelease(
        ptr_to_release: *mut c_void
    );
}

fn main() {
    // let ptr = /*from other context*/
    WXRelease(ptr);
}
```

When I try to run this program, I get the following compilation error:
`Non-UTF-8 output: wxams.4kzsx1adypypail6.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: Missing external symbol __imp__WXRelease@4, which is referenced in function "hb72ac0487c2750d0".`

If I change `stdcall` to `C` or `cdecl`, the compilation can proceed successfully. However, due to the calling convention mismatch, the program cannot run properly.

Is there any way to statically link this DLL instead of using dynamic calls to access the functions inside the DLL? In other words, is there a way to prevent name mangling from occurring with `stdcall`?

What I tried:

1. `#[no_mangle]`, no effects.
2. `#[link_name="..."]`, `@4` will be appended to the end of link name.
3. `extern "system"`, worked like `stdcall`

Comment: Have you looked at the [`no_mangle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html#the-no_mangle-attribute) and [`link_name`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html#the-link_name-attribute) attributes? Although the issue seems odd, [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#foreign-calling-conventions) shows a non-demangled `extern`, on the other hand threads like [RFC 674](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/674) and [internal 3973](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/no-no-mangle/3973) make things confusing.

Comment: Also maybe try `extern "system"` instead? It should automatically use the right external ABI for the current system, which [per the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/items/external-blocks.html#abi) is `"C"` on unices but `"stdcall"` on windows.

Comment: No, #[no_mangle] is signed like this: `#[no_mangle] has no effect on a foreign function`

Comment: Yes I've tried `extern "system"`, it worked like `stdcall`

Comment: If I use `link_name`, rust will append `@4` at the end of link_name :(

Comment: @NoobOfCpp Whats the symbol in the dll? Are you sure the @4 is incorrect, stdcall functions should end with @X, where x is the number of bytes in the argument list.

Comment: @user1937198 This is a third-party library, and I don't understand why all the stdcall functions do not end with `@size`. If static linking is not possible, I can only try using `libloading` or other ways.

Comment: @NoobOfCpp Is static linking supported from C? If so, does it expect any special flags to the C compiler?